# How to use express with webpack code splitting and react router?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am statically serving up my different bundle chunks that webpack generates in express under `some/route`, which happens to be the public path of the webpack config for the server/client.

I'm using SSR and react router via express to help optimize some of the load. When I go to root, the bundles load fine and works as expected. If I go to another route and refresh, the bundle requested is undefined. I'm trying to determine how I should best set up code splitting via express to work well with SSR.

```
app.use("/search/catalog", expressStaticGzip("public"));
app.use('/', router)
```

This is currently the set up, but feel the first definition is clobbering the rest, which might be breaking it? I can post more code depending on what would be useful.

Comment: So CSR is working for other routes but not SSR, how are the non-root routes being served? Also a bit confused on what you mean by bundle is undefined, does this mean it that route is not being server-rendered or that it is rendered into HTML but some other dynamic bundle is not being fetched?

Comment: So the request I see when I hit a particular route is `http://localhost:4000/search/catalog/undefined` where it should be the proper bundle chunk. It works if I load the root and navigate around, but not when I just do a hard refresh (SSR) on a different route other than the root.

Comment: It seems like it's not properly locating the bundle I need when doing the SSR.. Just seeing undefined - so that explains that. I guess I need to determine how to locate the correct bundle

Comment: So you visit some non-root route, it responds with some SSR'd React/HTML, the HTML has a `<script />` tag whose `src` is `/search/catalog/undefined`?

Comment: @adamz4008 I got it working. I crawled the dir with the statically created bundles and found the root bundle. Webpack takes over and loads the correct bundle from there.